# Puma error on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

After deploy on production server, puma get error:

```
2017-06-06 17:30:33 +0000: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for Puma:Module>
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/puma-3.9.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/puma-3.9.0/lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/puma-3.9.0/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/puma-3.9.0/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/puma-3.9.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/puma-3.9.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Ubuntu 16.04, Ruby 2.2.2, RoR 5.0.3, Puma 3.9.

Comment: I think we'll probably need more information than this. What is the app you are running? What is the rack app?

Comment: Fixed data about the application. What other data are needed?

Comment: I just don't think you're going to get much help here - there's no way for us to help because there's no information on what the app is, what you changed recently, etc.

Comment: It's first's deploy on production server.  Puma get this error.